# Updating > 1000 records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm currently trying to perform more than 1000 update statements in preparation for migrating data from one table to another in our Oracle DB.

I have a script which currently loops through all the records which will be affected with the column that will be updated and prints out each individual update statement... (ex. below)

```
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 3;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1319;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1324;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1329;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Yellow/IDMZ' WHERE ID = 1332;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1333;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1344;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1359;
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1361;
....
```

I'm trying to find the best way of running all of these update statements (or some entirely different method) w/o having to bog down performance or group up a set of statements and run them in chunks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Insert them into a table and update across an inner join?

Comment: Don't make your solution more complex due to performance. For 1k updates, it won't be an issue in the first place. The script will run extremely quickly as long as the table is indexed by ID.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, my script was created to generate the 1000 of update statements which I will copy into pl/sql and execute. I tried running 200 in our test environment and it took 5 minutes to initialize it.

Comment: It shouldn't be that slow.. the overhead of running individual statements vs bulking them is not much. If the update is slow, look at indexes and table structure on that table, as well as whether optimiser statistics are up to date.

Comment: im horrified seeing that approaches

Answer (score -1):

You could try converting then into chunks of anonymous PL/SQL blocks of say 200 updates e.g.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 3;
-- 200 more updates
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1319;
END;
BEGIN
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1324;
-- 200 more updates
UPDATE F_ASSET SET ZONE = 'Green/EHNET' WHERE ID = 1329;
END;
```

There is nothing special about 200, but too many and you'll hit some limit.  You could edit the begin/ends in by hand.
Now you only have 5 statements to execute. VERY ugly but, as it's a one off, it may be very effective. Wash your hands afterwards!

Using a Toad window or TSR (Toad Script Runner) this will buy you 10 to 100 times performance improvement due to it's "per statement" overhead.  It's useful when building simple insert/update statements in Excel from user data.  Every self respecting DBA will hate/downvote it as it's not a production solution but in practice for one off's, it just works.